# 500 Internal Errors using Google's URL shortener service API

Tags: google-apis-explorer, google-url-shortener

I'm trying to complete the JavaScript track on Codecademy, which requires an api key to access Google's URL shortener service. When I try to shorten, whether there or even when using the API's explorer page, I get errors.

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
{
 "longUrl": "https://freecodecamp.org"
}


500 Internal Server Error

cache-control:  private, max-age=0
content-encoding:  gzip
content-length:  122
content-type:  application/json; charset=UTF-8
date:  Tue, 02 Jan 2018 18:13:54 GMT
expires:  Tue, 02 Jan 2018 18:13:54 GMT
server:  GSE
vary:  Origin, X-Origin



{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "backendError",
    "message": "Backend Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 500,
  "message": "Backend Error"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah... we're getting that too...
I believe Google Shortening service is currently down...